# How to quickly find a file by name in package explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, find

How to quickly find a file by name in package explorer in Eclipse?  I know that Ctrl+Shift+R and type in the first few letters of the name of the file, can open the file, but the caveat is that the last time I opened the file in a different software but not Eclipse's own editor, and that preference is sticky.  I have to locate it in the package explorer first, and change to open it with Eclipse's default way.  I'm looking for an efficient way of locating the file by name, something better than opening nesting collapsed directory names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on the **menubar** at `Search`-->`File`--> And than type in the name of your file. You can also choose, which filetype your file is, In which part of eclipse you want to search etc.

[image]